# Why Managed package test classes didn't pass when activating SF Release S'21?

Tags: critical-update, release-notes

When i activated SF-Release **Enforce Access Modifiers on Apex Properties in Lightning Component Markup** and i runned all test classes in my org , Managed package test classes didn't Pass for some reasons ..

What will be the impact on my org? especially when i don't have access to Managed package apex classes

Comment: Did they pass before the upgrade? It's pretty common for managed package Apex classes to fail in subscriber orgs.

Comment: yes they passed before activating the release .. what do you mean by subscriber orgs ?

Comment: Sorry. ISV jargon. Subscriber orgs are orgs that contain a managed package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct impact on your org from managed package Apex tests failing. The impact would be if the test failure represents a genuine functional failure in the managed package after this critical update. You'd need to either test the package's functionality yourself or work with your package vendor to be sure.

The failing tests themselves don't do any harm. Managed packages' Apex tests often fail in customer orgs. They will not alter your Apex code coverage or prevent you from deploying, so long as you do not choose to Run All Tests during your deployments. Use Local Tests or Specified Tests instead.